# Spring data mongo @Query bind date

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have a spring mongo repository with the following method

```
@Query(value = "{'topicId':{$in: ?0},'ts':{$gt:{$date:?2}, $lte:{$date:?3}}, 'status': {$ne:?4}, 'seen':?1 }")
    public Page<NotificationReference> findByTopicIdInAndSeenAndStatusNot(List<String> topicIds, Boolean seen,
            Date from, Date to, String status, Pageable pageable);
```

But the ?2 and ?3 date variables are not resolving to their values.  I'm passing  a `java.util.Date` to the method, how do I get spring to resolve date variables for mongo queries?

Comment: Have you tried to ommit the $date keywords? I mean something like this: **@Query(value = "{'topicId':{$in: ?0},'ts':{$gt:?2}, $lte:?3}}, 'status': {$ne:?4}, 'seen':?1 }")**

Comment: That worked thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using $date should be enough.

```
 @Query(value = "{'topicId':{$in: ?0},'ts':{$gt:{$date:?2}, $lte:{$date:?3}}, 'status': {$ne:?4}, 'seen':?1 }")
```